# can i set pts and dts on opus codec like H.264 code

Tags: encoding, gstreamer, h.264, rtp, opus

i wrote a gstreamer c program to recive a h264 encoded rtp stream and  then change  pts and dts of the h264 video.can i do the same for opus encoded stream . Does opus encoding have pts and dts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ran the same code for opus and it works .